# Micro-controller and microphone minimal current possible

Tags: microcontroller, adc, microchip, low-power, microphone

We would like to have an idea about the minimal current consumption that could be achieve.

We need to have some microchip mcu, that have a microphone connected to its ADC port, and that is **always** listening, and waiting to get a certain frequency.

I know in sleep mode its less than 1mA, but we probably would have to add some amplifier to the microphone (or not?) and he will take much more.

Another option is to use LM567 that will waits for that frequency to appear, than awake the mcu — in that case, we still need an amplifier, and also LM567 consumption.
I am wondering, what is the best approach, and what's (more or less) the minimal current can be achieve, and how (architecture).

**Are there microphones that react only to some frequency?**

Comment: Define "always" in terms of how quickly you need to respond to a change - what appears almost instant in human terms can still be a decent sleep cycle for a processor.  But also consider what sort of time-response characteristic you want to avoid false detection, or false absence when noise interferes.  And what actual detection algorithm will you use?  A mere "is this frequency present" check can easily see a fake component in background noise more strongly than a true but weak signal in a quiet environment.

Answer (score 1):

1) To answer your bold question: Microphones usually have pretty large dynamic range. If you only want a specific part of the frequency spectrum, I would advise using some sort of *[a filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28signal_processing%29)*. This can either be done in hardware, or software. As consumption is a concern to you, I advise the first option.

2) To get the consumption as low as possible, you need to sleep as much as you can, make use of [DMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) and generally do as many things as you can in hardware (passive, if possible).

I am not the right person to answer which Microchip part would suit you best though.

Comment: 1. its not relevant, because a filter is nice, but the mcu still has to listen to it always. if i want only to interrupt the mcu,than the power will go to the tone decoder. detecting frequrncy in the mcu-or filtering-means always works. hence, these solution are bad for me, but thanks.

Comment: @Curnelious are you designing an audio remote control kind of thing? what is the frequency to be detected by the microphone?